# Why does resque use child processes for processing each job in a queue?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

We have been using Resque in most of our projects, and we have been happy with it.

In a recent project, we were having a situation, where we are making a connection to a live streaming API from the twitter. Since, we have to maintain the connection, we were dumping each line from the streaming API to a resque queue, lest the connection is not lost. And we were, processing the queue afterwards.

We had a situation where the insertion rate into the queue was of the order 30-40/second and the rate at which the queue is popped was only 3-5/second. And because of this, the queue was always increasing. When we checked for reasons for this, we found that resque had a parent process, and for each job of the queue, it forks a child process, and the child process will be processing the job. Our rails environment was quite heavy and the child process forking was taking time.

So, we implemented another rake task of this sort, for the time being:

```
rake :process_queue => :environment do
  while true
    begin
      interaction = Resque.pop("process_twitter_resque")
      if interaction
        ProcessTwitterResque.perform(interaction)
      end
    rescue => e
      puts e.message
      puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

and started the task like this:

```
nohup bundle exec rake process_queue --trace >> log/workers/process_queue/worker.log 2>&1 &
```

This does not handle failed jobs and all.

But, my question is why does Resque implement a child forked process to process the jobs from the queue. The jobs definitly does not need to be processed paralelly (since it is a queue and we expect it to process one after the other, sequentially and I beleive Resque also fork only 1 child process at a time).

I am sure Resque has done it with some purpose in mind. What is the exact purpose behind this parent/child process architecture?

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby process that sits and listens for jobs in Redis is not the process that ultimately runs the job code written in the perform method. It is the “master” process, and its only responsibility is to listen for jobs. When it receives a job, it forks yet another process to run the code. This other “child” process is managed entirely by its master. The user is not responsible for starting or interacting with it using rake tasks. When the child process finishes running the job code, it exits and returns control to its master. The master now continues listening to Redis for its next job.

The advantage of this master-child process organization – and the advantage of Resque processes over threads – is the isolation of job code. Resque assumes that your code is flawed, and that it contains memory leaks or other errors that will cause abnormal behavior. Any memory claimed by the child process will be released when it exits. This eliminates the possibility of unmanaged memory growth over time. It also provides the master process with the ability to recover from any error in the child, no matter how severe. For example, if the child process needs to be terminated using kill -9, it will not affect the master’s ability to continue processing jobs from the Redis queue.

In earlier versions of Ruby, Resque’s main criticism was its potential to consume a lot of memory. Creating new processes means creating a separate memory space for each one. Some of this overhead was mitigated with the release of Ruby 2.0 thanks to copy-on-write. However, Resque will always require more memory than a solution that uses threads because the master process is not forked. It’s created manually using a rake task, and therefore must load whatever it needs into memory from the start. Of course, manually managing each worker process in a production application with a potentially large number of jobs quickly becomes untenable. Thankfully, we have pool managers for that.

Answer (score 0):

Resque uses #fork for 2 reasons (among others): ability to prevent zombie workers (just kill them) and ability to use multiple cores (since it's another process).

Maybe this will help you with your fast-executing jobs: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2012/12/28/resque-worker-performance